# How to figure out the package version from "apt-cache show" output if there's two packages?

Tags: apt, apt-cache

I've never seen that `apt-cache show [exact package name]` shows two package information blocks (after `sudo apt-get clean`):

```
> sudo apt-cache show nvidia-367
Package: nvidia-367
Priority: optional
Section: restricted/misc
Installed-Size: 18
Maintainer: Ubuntu Core Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: amd64
Source: nvidia-graphics-drivers-375
Version: 375.66-0ubuntu0.17.04.1
Depends: nvidia-375
Filename: pool/restricted/n/nvidia-graphics-drivers-375/nvidia-367_375.66-0ubuntu0.17.04.1_amd64.deb
Size: 6498
MD5sum: 49948d6c82c69fcdbbb1bc2fc5805283
SHA1: 5fee5c7fb976d2d4eb7b135f98b814145a765c26
SHA256: 45024dcca31ecbcd8942625e06f39af9d9e44602e51077e1e3b97c75b6814d7d
Description-en: Transitional package for nvidia-375
 This is a transitional package for nvidia-375, and can be
 safely removed after the installation is complete.
Description-md5: 9e0e59c93b4df26deb06747b14fe9df1
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Origin: Ubuntu
Supported: 9m

Package: nvidia-367
Priority: optional
Section: restricted/misc
Installed-Size: 17
Maintainer: Ubuntu Core Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: amd64
Source: nvidia-graphics-drivers-375
Version: 375.39-0ubuntu5
Depends: nvidia-375
Filename: pool/restricted/n/nvidia-graphics-drivers-375/nvidia-367_375.39-0ubuntu5_amd64.deb
Size: 4786
MD5sum: d800639aa42e21dd512d2a2670d62a8b
SHA1: a4c0875c6ccdd5505eb2bae1d843695fd3d1d28a
SHA256: 278201b65afb594ad73b9d5a70e5cd51595628237082e72f9674e19d0c3d8a61
Description-en: Transitional package for nvidia-375
 This is a transitional package for nvidia-375, and can be
 safely removed after the installation is complete.
Description-md5: 9e0e59c93b4df26deb06747b14fe9df1
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Origin: Ubuntu
Supported: 9m
```

Which block should I refer to in order to figure out which version I'm using?

I'm using Ubuntu 17.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to know which version you are using then use other tools:

```
dpkg -l nvidia-367
```

or :

```
apt-cache policy nvidia-367
```

With `apt-cache` it happens when there are two version of a software available  in repository.

You can also use `apt show` instead of `apt-cache` to get most recent versions info.

or specify version too:

```
apt-cache show package-name=1.17.1-1ubuntu1.1
```

Comment: Or `apt-cache show --no-all-versions`, which seems to give the same result as the (newer) `apt show` i.e. the default value of `APT::Cache::AllVersions` is apparently opposite in `apt-cache` versus `apt`

Comment: +1 Good to know, I was poking around the man page but I didn't found about it... it seems candidate version will be displayed which in most cases is same as most recent.